# Prove the symmetry property of weights in the Newton-Cotes formula of quadrature

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I need to prove the symmetry property of the weights in the Newton-Cotes quadrature formula, that is $w_k = w_{n-k}.$ We may use the expression $$w_k = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \prod_{j=0,j\neq k}^n \frac{s-j}{k-j}ds, \,\,k = 0,...,n.$$
For the index $k$ we get: $$w_k =\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \frac{s(s-1)(s-2)\cdots (s-k+1)(s-k-1)\cdots(s-n)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1\cdot(-1)(-2)\cdots (k-n)}ds.$$ This leads to: $$w_k = \frac{1}{(-1)^{n-k}nk!(n-k)!}\int_0^n s(s-1)(s-2)\cdots (s-k+1)(s-k-1)\cdots(s-n)ds.$$
Accordingly, one gets for the index $n-k:$
$$w_{n-k} = \frac{1}{(-1)^{k}nk!(n-k)!} \int_0^n s(s-1)(s-2)\cdots (s-n+k+1)(s-n + k-1)\cdots (s-n)ds.$$

I do not know how to go from here. More precisely, I need to handle the integrals. Do you have any suggestion how to tackle the problem or you may want to propose a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: It should follow from the fact that the weights come from polynomial interpolation where the nodes are symmetric about 0. The uniqueness of the polynomial interpolation seems useful.

Comment: When you replace $k$ with $n-k$, also change $j$ to $n-j$ and $s$ to $n-s$. Discuss why the latter two changes, individually or in combination, do not change the integral.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But you are saying at one hand to replace the three variables at the same time and yet to consider individual changes of these variables. This is a little bit unclear. Do you think that the product in the integrand should be represented by means of factorials or some form of binomial coefficients? If one takes $n=2,$ one realizes that the integrand  for $k=0$ and $k=n-0$ are not the same but the integral of both is the same. It means that one has to somehow take the integral to prove the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question (at the time of writing) is 8 months old, I doubt @user996159 still needs an answer. However I want to provide one for anyone else finding this question.

Let $I=[a,b]$ and $x_i \in I$ with $x_0=a$, $x_n = b$ and $\forall i=1,\dots,n\colon x_i > x_{i-1}$. We define

$$
\ell_i(x) = \prod_{\substack{k=0\\k\neq i}}^n \frac{x-x_k}{x_i-x_k}\qquad
\chi = \frac{a+b}{2}\qquad
\widetilde{w}_i = \int_I \ell_i(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$

Notice that my answer requires that you show $\ell_i(x) = \ell_{n-i}(2\chi-x)$. For the following integrals, we introduce the
substitution $u = 2\chi-x$, i.e. $\mathrm{d}u = -\mathrm{d}x$:

$$
\widetilde{w}_{n-i} = \int_a^b\ell_{n-i}(x)\mathrm{d}x
= -\int_{2\chi-a}^{2\chi-b}\ell_{n-i}(2\chi-x)\mathrm{d}x
= -\int_{2\chi-a}^{2\chi-b}\ell_i(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
= -\int_b^a \ell_i(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b\ell_i(x)\mathrm{d}x 
= \widetilde{w}_i
$$